# How to blit a dialogue box in pygame until the player is in a specified vicinity

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game in python and want a dialogue box (png file) to be blitted on the screen as long as the player is in a defined vicinity that I set using the rect function. if I load the sprite and try to blit it directly it doesn't show up for some reason, can anyone help with this? ive attached concerned parts of the code below and the entire code is here on my [Github](https://github.com/Batsy24/Pokemon-game-.git):

```py
dialoguebox = pygame.image.load('dialogue box.png')
```

```py
npc1 = pygame.Rect(192, 226, 26, 32)
player_rect = playerImg.get_rect(topleft=(playerX, playerY))

if player_rect.colliderect(npc1):
    screen.blit(dialoguebox, (0, 0))
    if playerX_change > 0:
        player_rect.right = npc1.left
    elif playerX_change < 0:
        player_rect.left = npc1.right
    playerX = player_rect.x  # NPC near patch 


player_rect = playerImg.get_rect(topleft=(playerX, playerY))

if player_rect.colliderect(npc1):
    screen.blit(dialoguebox, (0, 0))
    if playerY_change < 0:
        player_rect.top = npc1.bottom
    elif playerY_change > 0:
        player_rect.bottom = npc1.top
    playerY = player_rect.y  # NPC near patch 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box doesn't show up, because the screen is cleared and redrawn in `redrawgamewindow()`.

Add a variable `current_dialogue` in global namespace:

```py
current_dialogue = None
```

Set the variable in the main application loop. `current_dialogue` is assigned a tuple (`(dialoguebox, (0, 0))`) which stores the information about the dialog.

```py
def game():
    global current_dialogue

    # [...]
 
    while running:
        current_dialogue = None
        
        # [...]

        if player_rect.colliderect(npc1):
            current_dialogue = (dialoguebox, (0, 0))
            # [...]

   
        # [...]

        redrawgamewindow()
 
        # [...]
```

And draw the dialog at the end of `redrawgamewindow()`. Use The  [asterisk(*) operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) to unpack the tuple (`scr.blit(*current_dialogue)`):

```py
def redrawgamewindow():
    # [...]
    scr.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # [...]

    if current_dialogue:
        scr.blit(*current_dialogue)
```

---

Note, the dialog will only show up, if the rectangles are intersecting. If you want the dialog to show up if the player is *near* the traget then you have to use an increased rectangle for the collision test. Use `inflate()` to generate a new rectangle with the changed size:

```py
if player_rect.inflate(5, 5).colliderect(npc1):
    current_dialogue = (dialoguebox, (0, 0))
```

Comment: Hello! this works pretty well, the dialogue box shows up too but it acts weird when I add the inflate function in both/either the parts of the code, like if im walking towards the npc from a certain direction and once the box pops up and I try to move in any direction except directly backwards on my original path it teleports me all over the place, also im quite new to programming can you please briefly explain what your code is actually doing?, thank you!

Comment: @pythonnewbie Sorry, but you have to debug your application yourself. I just can help you to solve the obvious mistakes

Comment: ah that's alright thank you anyway! but what's exactly happening in the code you've written? im still a little lost

Comment: @pythonnewbie You have to draw the dialog box in `redrawgamewindow`.  `current_dialogue` stores the information you have to draw. `current_dialogue` is assigned the tuple `(dialoguebox, (0, 0))`. The  [asterisk(*) operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) unpacks the tuple `scr.blit(*current_dialogue)`